# how to resolve the issue if application contains an invalid value in adobe flex mobile development?

Tags: mobile, air, resolve

i am new developer to work on adobe flex mobile development.I have try for SQLite in a sample application on Employee directory.I have implemented code for it then i have lunched the application in android simulator through eclipse then it has worked fine but when i lunch the same application in android real device then it is showing an error as follows:

```
       Error occurred while packaging the application:

C:\Documents and Settings\prasad\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\EmployeeDirectory\bin-     debug\EmployeeDirectory-app.xml(219): error 105: application contains an invalid value
C:\Documents and Settings\prasad\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\EmployeeDirectory\bin-debug\EmployeeDirectory-app.xml(219): error 105: application contains an invalid value
C:\Documents and Settings\prasad\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\EmployeeDirectory\bin-debug\EmployeeDirectory-app.xml(246): error 105: application contains an invalid value
```

so how can i resolve the above issue in android real device through adobe flex mobile development.

The following code of **EmployeeDirectory-app.xml**

```
<!-- A universally unique application identifier. Must be unique across all AIR applications.
Using a reverse DNS-style name as the id is recommended. (Eg. com.example.ExampleApplication.) Required. -->
<id>EmployeeDirectory</id>

<!-- Used as the filename for the application. Required. -->
<filename>EmployeeDirectory</filename>

<!-- The name that is displayed in the AIR application installer. 
May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
<name>EmployeeDirectory</name>

<!-- A string value of the format <0-999>.<0-999>.<0-999> that represents application version which can be used to check for application upgrade. 
Values can also be 1-part or 2-part. It is not necessary to have a 3-part value.
An updated version of application must have a versionNumber value higher than the previous version. Required for namespace >= 2.5 . -->
<versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>

<!-- A string value (such as "v1", "2.5", or "Alpha 1") that represents the version of the application, as it should be shown to users. Optional. -->
<!-- <versionLabel></versionLabel> -->

<!-- Description, displayed in the AIR application installer.
May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
<!-- <description></description> -->

<!-- Copyright information. Optional -->
<!-- <copyright></copyright> -->

<!-- Publisher ID. Used if you're updating an application created prior to 1.5.3 -->
<!-- <publisherID></publisherID> -->

<!-- Settings for the application's initial window. Required. -->
<initialWindow>
    <!-- The main SWF or HTML file of the application. Required. -->
    <!-- Note: In Flash Builder, the SWF reference is set automatically. -->
    <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>

    <!-- The title of the main window. Optional. -->
    <!-- <title></title> -->

    <!-- The type of system chrome to use (either "standard" or "none"). Optional. Default standard. -->
    <!-- <systemChrome></systemChrome> -->

    <!-- Whether the window is transparent. Only applicable when systemChrome is none. Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <transparent></transparent> -->

    <!-- Whether the window is initially visible. Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <visible></visible> -->

    <!-- Whether the user can minimize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
    <!-- <minimizable></minimizable> -->

    <!-- Whether the user can maximize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
    <!-- <maximizable></maximizable> -->

    <!-- Whether the user can resize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
    <!-- <resizable></resizable> -->

    <!-- The window's initial width in pixels. Optional. -->
    <!-- <width></width> -->

    <!-- The window's initial height in pixels. Optional. -->
    <!-- <height></height> -->

    <!-- The window's initial x position. Optional. -->
    <!-- <x></x> -->

    <!-- The window's initial y position. Optional. -->
    <!-- <y></y> -->

    <!-- The window's minimum size, specified as a width/height pair in pixels, such as "400 200". Optional. -->
    <!-- <minSize></minSize> -->

    <!-- The window's initial maximum size, specified as a width/height pair in pixels, such as "1600 1200". Optional. -->
    <!-- <maxSize></maxSize> -->

    <!-- The initial aspect ratio of the app when launched (either "portrait" or "landscape"). Optional. Mobile only. Default is the natural orientation of the device -->

    <!-- <aspectRatio></aspectRatio> -->

    <!-- Whether the app will begin auto-orienting on launch. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->

    <!-- <autoOrients></autoOrients> -->

    <!-- Whether the app launches in full screen. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->

    <!-- <fullScreen></fullScreen> -->

    <!-- The render mode for the app (either auto, cpu, or gpu). Optional. Mobile only. Default auto -->

    <!-- <renderMode></renderMode> -->

    <!-- Whether or not to pan when a soft keyboard is raised or lowered (either "pan" or "none").  Optional.  Defaults "pan." -->
    <!-- <softKeyboardBehavior></softKeyboardBehavior> -->
<autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <softKeyboardBehavior>none</softKeyboardBehavior>
</initialWindow>

<!-- We recommend omitting the supportedProfiles element, -->
<!-- which in turn permits your application to be deployed to all -->
<!-- devices supported by AIR. If you wish to restrict deployment -->
<!-- (i.e., to only mobile devices) then add this element and list -->
<!-- only the profiles which your application does support. -->
<!-- <supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop mobileDevice extendedMobileDevice</supportedProfiles> -->

<!-- The subpath of the standard default installation location to use. Optional. -->
<!-- <installFolder></installFolder> -->

<!-- The subpath of the Programs menu to use. (Ignored on operating systems without a Programs menu.) Optional. -->
<!-- <programMenuFolder></programMenuFolder> -->

<!-- The icon the system uses for the application. For at least one resolution,
specify the path to a PNG file included in the AIR package. Optional. -->
<!-- <icon>
    <image16x16></image16x16>
    <image32x32></image32x32>
    <image36x36></image36x36>
    <image48x48></image48x48>
    <image72x72></image72x72>
    <image114x114></image114x114>
    <image128x128></image128x128>
</icon> -->

<!-- Whether the application handles the update when a user double-clicks an update version
of the AIR file (true), or the default AIR application installer handles the update (false).
Optional. Default false. -->
<!-- <customUpdateUI></customUpdateUI> -->

<!-- Whether the application can be launched when the user clicks a link in a web browser.
Optional. Default false. -->
<!-- <allowBrowserInvocation></allowBrowserInvocation> -->

<!-- Listing of file types for which the application can register. Optional. -->
<!-- <fileTypes> -->

    <!-- Defines one file type. Optional. -->
    <!-- <fileType> -->

        <!-- The name that the system displays for the registered file type. Required. -->
        <!-- <name></name> -->

        <!-- The extension to register. Required. -->
        <!-- <extension></extension> -->

        <!-- The description of the file type. Optional. -->
        <!-- <description></description> -->

        <!-- The MIME content type. -->
        <!-- <contentType></contentType> -->

        <!-- The icon to display for the file type. Optional. -->
        <!-- <icon>
            <image16x16></image16x16>
            <image32x32></image32x32>
            <image48x48></image48x48>
            <image128x128></image128x128>
        </icon> -->

    <!-- </fileType> -->
<!-- </fileTypes> -->

<!-- iOS specific capabilities -->
<!-- <iPhone> -->
    <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Info.plist -->
    <!-- <InfoAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <string>1</string>
                <string>2</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
            <string>YES</string>
        ]]>
    </InfoAdditions> -->
    <!-- <requestedDisplayResolution></requestedDisplayResolution> -->
<!-- </iPhone> -->

<!-- Specify Android specific tags that get passed to AndroidManifest.xml file. -->
<android> 
    <manifestAdditions>
    <![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-configuration android:reqFiveWayNav="true"/>
            <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"/>
            <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
            <application android:enabled="true">
                <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
    ]]>
    </manifestAdditions> 
</android> 
--><!-- End of the schema for adding the android specific tags in AndroidManifest.xml file -->
```

See the Adobe AIR documentation for more information aboutsetting Google Androidpermissions
                Removing the permission android.permission.INTERNET will have the side effect
        of preventing you from debugging your application on your device
                
                
                
                
                The DISABLE_KEYGUARD and WAKE_LOCK permissions should be toggled together
        in order to access AIR's SystemIdleMode APIs
                
                
                
                
                The ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions should be toggled
        together in order to use AIR's NetworkInfo APIs

```
    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
--><iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

Comment: Can you put your EmployeeDirectory-app.xml ????

I think there is some problem with your app-xml file.

Comment: I have put the EmployeeDirectory-app.xml.please go through it

Comment: The formatting of the XML file affected the layout -- the important lines of code are ambiguous.  Can you post this XML file in a dropbox, or on your website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always look at your XML files in Firefox, or use [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) to open the XML.  Both of these are free resources that allow you to see if there are any errors.  I like Firefox because it shows only one error at a time, and it is very clear about the line number.  FlashDevelop has a tool that reformats your XML into a well-structured layout (menu item ***Refactor | Code Formatter***).

---

To help fix your specific problem, though, let's refer to the error messages:

```
[...]EmployeeDirectory-app.xml(219): error 105: application contains an invalid value
[...]EmployeeDirectory-app.xml(246): error 105: application contains an invalid value
```

These statements show that you have errors on lines 219 and 246.  Looking at the XML file, you can see that you have a "close comment" markup (`-->`) on each of those lines.

Let's take line 219 first.  Reading upwards in the file to find the "start comment" markup, there doesn't seem to be one.  So either remove this markup, or else add a "start comment" markup.

Now line 246.  At first, this may also seem like an extra "close comment" markup, but it is not.  Backtrack to it's "start comment" markup on line 222.  You can see that the "start comment" has no space between it and the markup it is trying to comment out.  Adding a space fixes this problem.

In general, I like to make my testing comment markup *very* explicit.  To make them easier to find, I usually give a line space above and below both the opening an closing markups.  E.g.:

```
<android1>
[...]
</android1>

<!-- 

<android2>
[...]
</android2>

-->

<android3>
[...]
</android3>
```

Note that I don't know if you have any errors in the XML *content* though.